# eBPF (bcc) on centos

Tags: linux, compiler-errors

It's possible deploy bcc --> https://iovisor.github.io/bcc/

... on centos /redhat SO?

someone knows what's the problem to compile bcc tools from centos? (all dependencies are installed), but when I execute the last step:

> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr

Returns:

> [root@ebpf build]# cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
>   -- Latest recognized Git tag is v0.3.0
>   -- Git HEAD is 007d28c534e1a98e6017ac9f4c8cb1c0f5244388
>   -- Revision is 0.3.0-007d28c5 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided
>   by "LLVM" with any of   the following names:
>
> ```
> LLVMConfig.cmake
> llvm-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "LLVM"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has been   installed.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/root/bcc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Answer (score 0):

for llvm issue. just run below CLI:
     `cp /usr/share/llvm/cmake/LLVM-Config.cmake /usr/share/llvm/cmake/llvm-config.cmake`